# Amazon S3 copy_object key not found - encoding problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded files from a JS-Frontend to Amazon S3. Using aws-sdk-s3 for Ruby I try to move objects then to a different bucket. I am using `Aws::S3::Client#copy_object` for this.

For testing purposes, I uploaded a file named `{}?^°!#*äÄÜ?=)(;:- &%$§%2!  |<>.jpg`. While everything works for files without special chars, moving this file results in an `Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument Exception: Unsupported copy source parameter` error.

I verified the file exists in my S3-Bucket under that name. Encoding the object-key in various ways (CGI.escape, URI.escape, URI.encode) did not help.

The snippet looks like this:

```
    s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])
    source_key = "{}?^°!#*äÄÜ?=)(;:- &%$§%2!  |<>.jpg"
    s3.copy_object({ copy_source: 'mybucket1/' + source_key,
                     bucket:      'mybucket2',
                     key:         'new_file_name.jpg' })
```

Does anyone have an idea, why the copy source is not found? Does the key include forbidden characters or do I have to encode them differently?

Comment: I have to agree on one thing. This is the most weirdest name given to a s3 object I have even seen :-D.

Comment: The error does not say the source object was not found.  It says the argument is "invalid" and "unsupported."  Have you verified what the error response would be with a simple (i.e. alphanumeric ASCII only) source object key that doesn't exist?

Comment: Oh, you're right. NoSuchKey is the error for an nonexisting key.

Comment: As the documentation says, The copy_source value must be URL encoded. Use CGI.escape() around the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transliteration did not the trick. I eventually figured it out by myself:
There were two problems: For form submission the filename got encoded, so special characters like `?`, `%` and `+` were escaped. I had to do a `URI.decode` on the key and then re-encode it by using `Aws::Sigv4::Signer.uri_escape(string)` of aws-sdk-ruby. Amazon does encoding differentely, which was the reason that things messed up. Have a look at the source of `uri_escape`:

```
def uri_escape(string)
  CGI.escape(string.encode('UTF-8')).gsub('+', '%20').gsub('%7E', '~')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you replace all special characters before sending to S3.

```
source_key = "{}?^°!#*äÄÜ?=)(;:- &%$§%2!  |<>" 
source_key = I18n.transliterate(source_key)
source_key.gsub! /\W/, '_'
source_key += '.jpg'
```

The first line is the source_key name without file extension (`.jpg`). The second line transforms any special characters to their closest character without accent (à -> a, é -> e, etc.). The third line transforms into '_' any character that's not in [a-zA-Z] range. The last line adds the file extension.